# How can store list of string into node?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to pass a string into the function, and return the linked list, that each node contains string.
So, in main function, as you can see

```
list = newTB("hello\ngood\nworld");
```

Then, newTB should return the list, which is like..

```
[hello]-> [good]-> [world]->null
```

There must be error in my newTB function since seg fault keeps come out..

Anyone please help me..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "textbuffer.h"

#define MAX_TEXT 256

typedef struct textbuffer *TB;

struct textbuffer {
    char *texts;
    int count;     // counts how many nodes in the list
    TB next;
};

void printBuffer(TB tb){
    TB curr = tb;
    int i=0;
    while(curr != NULL){
        printf("POS %d : %s\n", i++, curr->texts);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

int linesTB(TB tb) {
    return (tb->count);
}

TB newTB (char text[]){
    TB newText = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
    char *cpy = (char *)malloc(MAX_TEXT * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(cpy,text);
    newText->count = 0;
    newText->next = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while( cpy[i] != '\0') {
        if( j == 0) {
            newText->texts = (char *)malloc(MAX_TEXT * sizeof(char));
        }
        if(cpy[i] == '\n') {
            newText->count++;
            newText->next = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
            newText = newText->next;
            j = 0;   
        } else {
            newText->texts[j++] = cpy[i++];
        }
    }
    return newText;
}

void releaseTB (TB tb) {
    TB head = tb;
    TB tmp;

    while(head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp->texts);
        free(tmp);

    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    TB list = NULL;
    list = newTB("hello\ngood bye\nworld\n");

    printf("**THERE ARE %d LINES IN TEXTBUFFER**\n", linesTB(list));
    printBuffer(list);
    printf("%s\n",dumpTB(list));
    releaseTB(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where does it segfault?

Comment: I think, you miss your head here: `newText = newText->next;` Isn't it?

Comment: And you initialize newText->count only for head node.

Comment: `newTB` returns `newText` when it's done. What is `newText` actually pointing to at that point, when the function has been passed `hello\ngood\nworld`?

Comment: Right now `newTB` never returns.  It allocates `newTB`s until it runs out of memory.

Comment: it seg faults at newText->texts = (char *)malloc(MAX_TEXT * sizeof(char));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing `i` here. So it is looping there only.

```
if(cpy[i] == '\n') 
{
    newText->count++;
    newText->next = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
    newText = newText->next;
    j = 0;   
}
```

I modified the code and here is what I have done.

```
TB newTB (char text[]){
    TB newText = (TB )malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
    char *cpy = (char *)malloc(MAX_TEXT * sizeof(char));
    TB root = newText; // Store the first node to return 
    TB prv = newText; // not required. Added for testing by me
    int cnt = 0;
    strcpy(cpy,text);
    newText->count = 0;
    newText->next = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;


    while( cpy[i] != '\0') {
        if( j == 0) {
            prv->texts = (char *)malloc(MAX_TEXT * sizeof(char));
        }
        if(cpy[i] == '\n') {
            prv->texts[j++] = '\0'; // As Rohan suggested.
            //newText->count++;
            prv->next = (TB )malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
            prv = prv->next;  // not required. Added for testing by me
            //newText = newText->next; 
            j = 0;   
            i++; // Increment i here
        } else {
            prv->texts[j++] = cpy[i++];
        }
    }
    return root; // Return the root node.
}
```

**Edit**

```
//Printing the node
void printBuffer(TB tb){
    TB curr = tb;
    int i=0;
    while(curr->next != NULL){ // changed from curr!=NULL to curr->next!=NULL
        printf("POS %d : %s\n", i++, curr->texts);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Also added

```
prv->next = NULL; // Added this line in newTB  function
return root;
```

Comment: this code seems work.. but at the end of the list, it is printing out 'null' as well..

Comment: it is correctly linking.. but when i printed out for testing..POS 0 : hello
POS 1 : good bye
POS 2 : what
POS 3 : (null)
/// it should be like .. POS 0 : hello POS 2 : good bye POS 3 : what

Comment: I have updated the code... Add prv->next = NULL; in the newTB  function before you return root node.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of little problems, but here's the big one:

```
    if(cpy[i] == '\n') {
        newText->count++;
        newText->next = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
        newText = newText->next;
        j = 0;   
    }
```

if `cpy[i]` is a newline, you make a `newText`.  Guess what you don't do: advance `i`.  So you keep running this code over and over until you run out of memory.

If I was going to rewrite this, I would not scan through the code character by character, but instead use `strchr()` to find line breaks.  Also, you already copy the string once (using `strdup` would be more efficient and easier), use that duplicated string and chop it up and assign the parts of it to the `textblock` so each `textblock` doesn't need its own string.

Answer (score 0):

Once you copy character by character in `newText->texts` terminate it with `'\0'` so that it becomes appropriately null terminated string.

```
       if(cpy[i] == '\n') {
            nextText->texts[j] = '\0'; //set null terminated string.
            newText->count++;
            newText->next = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
            newText = newText->next;
            j = 0;   
        } else {
            newText->texts[j++] = cpy[i++];
        }
```

Otherwise when you print string in `newText->texts` will not find termination character, and keep printing and accessing invalid memory, causing segfault.